# Sonarqube rule for JUnit packsge

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube

I am newbie to `sonar` and `junit`, I am writing `JUnit` for increasing `Sonarqube` code coverage, but `package` of `class` is not covering in that. If `class` is fully covered then also I am getting the low percent coverage. PFA screenshot of sample class.
My questions are:

1. Do I have to change anything in `sonar` configuration ?
2. Or is it possible to write `Junit` for it ?

[image: Screen Shot from sonar]

Comment: Just to be sure: when you run your JUnit tests with coverage; for example within your IDE; you achieve a higher number? It is just that SonarQube for some reason doesn't factor in the coverage "gained" by running unit tests?

Comment: SonarQube doesn't come out of the box with any code coverage engine. So you need to feed SonarQube with some code coverage reports and the issue you're talking about here is part of this code coverage report. And so, the question becomes: "Which code coverage tool are you using to get such unexpected behavior ?"

Comment: I am using built in `jacoco` of `sonarqube`